# POST multipart/form-data contents out of order

Tags: sockets, http, post

I am trying to build a web server using java sockets, everything is fine except when the browser sends POST request with file attached, when the request is received the content of the file is out of order , the file sent was txt file with line numbers when received the line numbers were out of order. is there any way I can avoid this I want ordered data (see pic 99522 is followed by 99712) THANKs

```
public class Server{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
    while(true) new Thread(new Client(server.accept())).start();
}

}


class Client implements Runnable {

Socket client;
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("File12"));
InputStream in;
OutputStream out;
static ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
String index;
String response;

Client(Socket client) throws IOException {
    String listOfFiles = "<ol>";
    this.client = client;
    in = client.getInputStream();
    out = client.getOutputStream();
    clients.add(client);
    for (File file : new File(".").listFiles()) if (file.isFile()) listOfFiles += "<li><a href=" + URLEncoder.encode(file.getName(), "UTF-8") + ">" + file.getName() + "</a></li>"; 
    listOfFiles += "</ol>";
    index = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>" + new Date() + "</h1><hr>"+listOfFiles+"<form id='upload' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='/upload'><input id='fileupload' multiple name='myfile' type='file' /><input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit' /></form></body></html>";  
    response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                "Content-Length:"+index.length()+"\r\n" +
                "\r\n" +
                index;

}

public void run() {

    try {
        String msg = "";
        byte buffer[] = new byte[32*1024];
        int read = in.read(buffer);
        while(read != -1){
            msg = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println(msg);
            if(msg.startsWith("POST")){
                System.err.println("RAN IN POST");
                out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
                out.write("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n".getBytes());
                out.write(("Content-Length:"+ 4 +"\r\n").getBytes());
                out.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                out.write("done".getBytes());

            }
            if(msg.startsWith("GET")){
                String path = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("/"), msg.indexOf("HTTP")).trim();
                if(path.equals("/")) out.write(response.getBytes());
                else {
                    String fileName = path.substring(1);
                    fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName,"UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    if(file.exists()){
                        System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());
                        out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
                        out.write("Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n".getBytes());
                        out.write(("Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n").getBytes());
                        out.write("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n".getBytes());
                        out.write(("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"\r\n").getBytes());
                        out.write("\r\n".getBytes()); 
                        try{
                            Files.copy(Paths.get(file.getPath()) , out);
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            break;
                        }
                    }else System.out.println("file not existes");
                }
            }
            out.flush();
            os.close();
            read = in.read(buffer);
        }
        System.err.println("closing scoket");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        client.close();
        clients.remove(client);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ALL right found the bug I am not clearing the buffer hence it appears again